# Django Forms - set field as blank if field contains errors

Tags: django, django-forms

In a form, I'd like to have certain fields that are set as blank if they contain any validation errors. For example, if I have a decimal field called `price` and it has an invalid value of *blue*, I'd like just silently set the field to none.

This would be used to make search filters via query strings so if there is a better solution, please let me know.

**Edit 2**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField()
    price = forms.DecimalField(required=False)
```

I'd like the form to be able to handle invalid field values in a way that the form does not become invalid. For example, if I have `?q=car&price=100` the form would work. If I have `?q=car&price=circle`, I'd like the form to notice the error (value isn't a decimal) but instead of making the form invalid, just make the field blank.

The `clean_*` would be useful for validating non field type specific errors, yes? (Field type related errors would have already been checked and invalidated the form). If so, how should I go about detecting these errors?

My approach could be totally wrong here - I'm basically trying to create search filters.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the `clean_field` method is for. So for example in your example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def clean_price(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['price']
        if value == 'blue':
            value = ''
        return value
```

Comment: How can I catch normal field validation errors (which I'd then reset fields) so they don't end up making my form as invalid?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking that isn't covered by my answer already. Can you give an example?

Comment: I've edited my original question. Hopefully that helps. Please let me know - Thanks